# Why am I getting a syntax error at my $in command?

Tags: database, mongodb

```
for rest in restaurants.find({},{"restaurant_id" : 0,"name":1,"borough":1, "cuisine":1, "_id":0},{"borough": {$in: ["Bronx", "Queens"]}}).limit(20):
       print(rest)
```

Why am I getting a syntax error at `$in`?

Updated mongoDB still getting syntax error at `$in`.

```
for rest in restaurants.find({"borough":{$in:["Bronx", "Queens"]},{"restaurant_id" : 0, "_id":0}}).limit(20):
       print(rest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), `find` allows only two parameters: Query and projection.

Docs says:

- Query: Specifies selection filter using query operators.
- Projection: Specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter.

But your query is like:

```
find({/*empty object*/}, {projection}, {query} )
```

Using en empty object as query is to get all data, like `SELECT *` in SQL. So, your query is wrong, because your are trying first get all data, then do a projection and in the end a query.

So, following docs you need something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tvnmgmz8kMX):

```js
db.collection.find({
  /* Query */
  "borough": {
    "$in": [
      "Bronx",
      "Queens"
    ]
  }
},
{
  /* Projection */
  "restaurant_id": 0,
  "_id": 0
})
```

Also note in projection is only possible indicate the values to be excluded. By default, all values from collection are shown, so you don't have to include. You only need to exclude values you don't want to retrieve.

Comment: thank you so much worked like a charm. i was so confused why i was getting a syntax error, I guess the problem lied elsewhere and not necessarily my $in

Comment: You forgot one `}` just before the comma and one of the last two is unnecessary. This works: `{"borough": {$in: ["Bronx","Queens"]}},{"restaurant_id": 0,"_id": 0}`

Comment: yea sorry misttyped